# Rsync command to large archive dir that has been changed

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, rsync

I have a Raspberry PI running as a media server that my other devices rsync to various dir. I have a great script that runs at 5am each day that checks for new files and runs

```
rsync --stats -P -ahuvz ~/EXT -e "ssh -v" user@ip:~/Vault/PI
```

I ran into an issue where I was trying to rsync too much in the EXT dir so I went and reorganized all of my files moving a bunch into a NoSync dir and divvying up the EXT dir into sections.

My problem is : Now it wants to create duplicate files on the dest dir rather than recognizing they are the same file just moved to a new dir (example EXT/BookA -> EXT/Books/BookA). I went through the rsync man page but didn't see any flag that might solve my issue - does anyone have an elegant solution to this, other than manually replicating the changes on dest ?

Answer (score 0):

An easiest option you have is to use [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download.html), which is much better at detecting file moves and renames than `rsync`.

It might be as simple as that:

```
%unison -batch ~/EXT ssh://user@ip//home/user/Vault/PI
```

But take care that `unison` is a bi-directional synchronization tool and `-batch` will auto-resolve all the conflicts for you.

That would normally work just nice, if your machines clocks are in sync and the file modification timestamps are ok.

If unsure, just omit `-batch` (or replace it with `-auto`) and it will prompt you to resolve conflicts.

> -auto  automatically accept default (nonconflicting) actions
>
> -batch batch mode: ask no questions at all

---

There are also a hard-link based technique, to detect moves and renames with `rsync`: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/detecting-file-moves-renames-rsync/

But it requires some preliminary steps, before the content is re-organized.

Comment: apparently this option isn't going to work bc unison requires exact version match and the PI version is 2.40 and the Ubuntu is 2.48 - i would have thought it would be simple to change version to 2.40 on both but apparently they are mismatched because the OS is mismatched.